# Return minimum "sub-DAG" generated from dictionary

Tags: python, algorithm, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have an input data and some transformation functions t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6. Each of them requires some columns as input and outputs some columns.

```
details = {
    't1': {
        input_cols = ['C1', 'C2'],
        output_cols = ['C8', 'C9', 'C10']
    }
    't2': {
        input_cols = ['C8', 'C10'],
        output_cols = ['C11', 'C12']
    }
    't3': {
        input_cols = ['C11', 'C12'],
        output_cols = ['C13', 'C14', 'C15', 'C16']
    },
    't4': {
        input_cols = ['C9', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5', 'C6'],
        output_cols = ['C17', 'C18', 'C19', 'C20']
    },
    't5': {
        input_cols = ['C20', 'C16'],
        output_cols = ['C21', 'C22']
    },
    't6': {
        input_cols = ['C7', 'C16'],
        output_cols = ['C23', 'C24', 'C25']
    }
}
```

The DAG associated with these transformations is

[image]

I get as input the columns I want to generate and I should return the sub-DAG required to obtain it (I am not interested only in the DAG nodes, the order also matters)
For example,

if the `required_columns` are
`['C1', 'C2,', ..., 'C25']`, the output should be
`['t1', 't2', 't3', 't5', 't4', 't6']` or other possible path such as `['t1', 't4', 't2', 't6', 't3', 't5']`

if the `required_columns` are ['C8', 'C9', 'C10', 'C11', 'C12', 'C13', 'C114', 'C15', 'C16', 'C20', 'C21', 'C22'] I should output ['t1', 't2', 't3', 't5']

if the `required_columns` are ['C1', 'C3', 'C5', 'C8', 'C9', 'C10', 'C11', 'C12', 'C17', 'C18', 'C19', 'C20'] I should output ['t1', 't4']

Note that the presence / absence of 'C1' ... 'C7' in my `required_columns` doesn't influence the desired output, as these columns are not generated by t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6

My approach for solving this problem would be:

1. Create a DAG D based on `details` dictionary
2. For each leaf in D
   if all the `output_cols` of the current leaf are not in the `required_columns` -> delete the node and move upwards to the nodes that point to the node and repeat the step
3. Print the values of the existing topological sorted trimmed DAG

I intuitively think my approach is far from optimal. Given the current input data format (`details` is a dictionary and `required_columns` is a list), how can I do better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build the transpose DAG and do depth-first search from the required columns?

```
import collections

Transformation = collections.namedtuple("Transformation", ["input_cols", "output_cols"])

details = {
    "t1": Transformation(input_cols=["C1", "C2"], output_cols=["C8", "C9", "C10"]),
    "t2": Transformation(input_cols=["C8", "C10"], output_cols=["C11", "C12"]),
    "t3": Transformation(
        input_cols=["C11", "C12"], output_cols=["C13", "C14", "C15", "C16"]
    ),
    "t4": Transformation(
        input_cols=["C9", "C3", "C4", "C5", "C6"],
        output_cols=["C17", "C18", "C19", "C20"],
    ),
    "t5": Transformation(input_cols=["C20", "C16"], output_cols=["C21", "C22"]),
    "t6": Transformation(input_cols=["C7", "C16"], output_cols=["C23", "C24", "C25"]),
}


def depth_first_search(graph, roots):
    stack = [(root, True) for root in roots]
    visited = set()
    order = []
    while stack:
        v, entering = stack.pop()
        if entering:
            if v in visited:
                continue
            visited.add(v)
            stack.append((v, False))
            stack.extend((w, True) for w in graph[v])
        else:
            order.append(v)
    return order


def sub_dag(required_columns):
    graph = collections.defaultdict(set)
    for k, v in details.items():
        for c in v.input_cols:
            graph[k].add(c)
        for c in v.output_cols:
            graph[c].add(k)
    order = depth_first_search(graph, required_columns)
    return [t for t in order if t in details]


print(
    sub_dag(
        [
            "C1",
            "C2",
            "C3",
            "C4",
            "C5",
            "C6",
            "C7",
            "C8",
            "C9",
            "C10",
            "C11",
            "C12",
            "C13",
            "C14",
            "C15",
            "C16",
            "C17",
            "C18",
            "C19",
            "C20",
            "C21",
            "C22",
            "C23",
            "C24",
            "C25",
        ]
    )
)
print(
    sub_dag(
        [
            "C8",
            "C9",
            "C10",
            "C11",
            "C12",
            "C13",
            "C14",
            "C15",
            "C16",
            "C20",
            "C21",
            "C22",
        ]
    )
)
print(
    sub_dag(
        [
            "C1",
            "C3",
            "C5",
            "C8",
            "C9",
            "C10",
            "C11",
            "C12",
            "C17",
            "C18",
            "C19",
            "C20",
        ]
    )
)
print(sub_dag(["C1", "C3", "C5", "C25", "C22"]))
```

Comment: Interesting, but it fails for `sub_dag(["C1", "C3", "C5", "C25", 'C22'])` if `t6` is renamed with `t06`, it returns {'t06', 't1', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5'} instead of {'t1', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5', 't06'} or other properly sorted set

Comment: @pentavol It's sorted by lexicographic order on strings, not numbers. You'd have to do something like sorted(sub_dag(...), key=lambda k: int(k[1:])) to get numeric order (ideally a library with more general handling unless you know that the transformation names are always t###).

Comment: perhaps my question wasn't clear enough. I don't need the results in lexicographic order, nor in numeric order. t6 depends on t2, therefore it should be printed after t2. I think that printing a topologically sorted trimmed DAG (DAG without nodes that are not required) is what I need.

Comment: @pentavol added a topsort.